# Where is remote web interface for Server 2008 R2? For starting applications

Tags: iis, remote, web, interface

I want to be able to start and stop (run and terminate) an application when it's needed, not programmatically but through a web interface. I noticed windows home server has a nice web interface shown in this article:
http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2007/03/windows-home-server-beta-2-part-3/ 
I was wondering if Server 2008 R2 has something similar for iis that allows me to do this? If not, then it doesn't have to start/stop applications, those features in the home server web interface seem nice to have too.

I also notice there's a role called "Application Server", though it's not a web interface, if I have to end up making my own web interface, I'd like to know whether those services leave a significant memory footprint or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no remote web interface comprable to the one in that article for Server 2008 R2.

Comment: That article was talked about home server mainly, so I assume it's also on Server 2008 R2? If so, how/where can I install it?
EDIT: Sorry I thought you meant there WAS one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [Terminal Services Web Access (TS Web Access)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771908%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

From the library:

> With TS Web Access, users can visit a Web site (either from the
>   Internet or from an intranet) to access a list of available RemoteApp
>   programs. When they start a RemoteApp program, a Terminal Services
>   session is started on the Windows Server® 2008-based terminal server
>   that hosts the RemoteApp program.

Comment: Oh thanks, this seems to be very close to what I was looking for for. A bit dependent on web browser capabilities (IE only) but thanks. Also in 2008 R2, Terminal Services was renamed to Remote Desktop Services, just for anyone's reference. Still looking for a fair web-browser independent version though.